# Price Equation in Evolution

Tags: evolution, homework, theoretical-biology

I am trying to solve for $\text{cov}(w_i,z_i)+E(w_i\Delta z_i)$ as it apears in Price Equations in terms of the mean $\overline{w}$ and variance $\sigma_{w}^2$ of the fitness of a population where I am given the relation $\Delta z_i=-cz_i$. I don't understand how we can solve this because I do not know how I have any knowledge of the values of the $w_i$s given what I know about the $z_i$s. Any hints would be appreciated.

The [Price Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_equation) is defined as:

$\Delta z = \frac{1}{w} cov(w_{i}, z_{i}) + \frac{1}{w} E(w_{i}\Delta z_{i})$

Comment: It would help to know if you are working from data ("what I know about the $z_{i}$s", "values of the $w_{i}$s") or just as a theoretical exercise. If you have data, getting an example would be helpful. Usually my understanding is that the Price equation is applied when we have knowledge of trait values and of fitness. It does not sound like you are doing theoretical work but it's hard to say based on the question.

Comment: The question was intended to be theoretical. The problem I was given was to first find the expectation in terms of the mean and variance of the fitness, and then to compute the right hand side of the Price equation (which I presumed also meant to compute $\text{cov}(w_i,z_i)$. This was all the information I was given, and I am not sure if I misunderstood some element of the Price equation or if there was not enough information given.

Comment: Seems like it might be better to ask for clarification from the person giving you the assignment (and edit this into your question, if it's helpful). Of course, if you do come up with an answer on your own it's perfectly acceptable to self-answer your own question.

Comment: I'm not an expert here so I won't answer in much depth (and for homeworks we want to see some evidence of work usually, see here for more info https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour), but I would suggest the standard algebraic tricks. E.g. look into the definition of covariance, consider a case where covariance approaches zero,  consider a case where covariance is complete.